# How to change libcurl SSL backend from gnutls to openssl on Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, openssl, curl, gnutls

I am getting gnutls specific errors in my Tornado webserver while processing Google OpenID SSL responses. One of the suggestions I got from Tornado mailing list is to try OpenSSL backend instead of gnutls. But it doesn't seem to be straightforward on Ubuntu server (11.10).

On Ubuntu server, `gnutls` is provided by `libcurl3-gnutls` package and openssl curl support is provided by `libcurl4-openssl-dev` package. (I don't know why the later is named `4` and `dev`, but I couldn't find any other openssl+curl package in apt-cache search).

I had `libcurl3-gnutls` installed by default, but not `libcurl4-openssl-dev`. So I installed the later and restarted Torando instances. But that didn't seem to work. I still got same gnutls errors.

I found old discussions on curl mailing lists regarding the problems of supporting different SSL backends to libcurl, but didn't find exactly how is it done today. So far my guess is openssl is built into libcurl and gnutls is provided through separate package (that will explain why there is no libcurl3-openssl). But how do I make libcurl to pick up openssl backend and not gnutls? Is there some option in libcurl/pycurl API to do this?

I tried uninstalling `libcurl3-gnutls`, but apt-get prompted that it will also remove `python-pycurl` along with it. So that won't do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-dev` packages are the development packages, they contain the library headers, used to develop and compile programs that use the library. They're usually not required by application binary packages (which are already compiled). Installing `libcurl4-openssl-dev` isn't enough to make the binary packages that have been built against `libcurl3-gnutls` use OpenSSL instead. It would only be useful for applications that you re-compile against it.

The `python-pycurl` package has a [direct dependency](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/python-pycurl) on `libcurl3-gnutls` and `libgnutls26`.

Unless there are cURL-based packages for Ubuntu compiled against OpenSSL instead of GnuTLS in an alternative repository, you may have to build them yourself unfortunately.

This could be do in principle by downloading the source (`apt-get source python-pycurl`, and related packages). You would have to go into the Debian packaging configuration files and change the options (usually passed to the `configure` script which also configures the `Makefile`s before compilation) so as to change the compilation options, to use OpenSSL instead. You may also need to change the package description to limit disruption to the other packages, perhaps by using the `provide:` directive to say that your package can replace the one packaged by Ubuntu.

Comment: As @SwenW said, [`libcurl3`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/libcurl3) is compiled against OpenSSL, so it should be a matter or changing the build options for OpenSSL and making `python-pycurl` depend on `libcurl3` instead of `libcurl3-gnutls`.

Answer (score 9):

I saw a solution on [Debian bug tracker](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=515200).

I figured I'd post a workaround for people to fix the `python-pycurl` 
package themselves.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential fakeroot dpkg-dev
mkdir ~/python-pycurl-openssl
cd ~/python-pycurl-openssl
sudo apt-get source python-pycurl
sudo apt-get build-dep python-pycurl
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
dpkg-source -x pycurl_7.18.2-1.dsc
cd pycurl-7.18.2
```

Note pycurl could have been updated so the name may not exactly be `pycurl_7.18.2-1.dsc`
Edit the `debian/control` file and replace all instances of 
`libcurl4-gnutls-dev` with `libcurl4-openssl-dev`

```
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -b
sudo dpkg -i ../python-pycurl_7.18.2-1_i386.deb
```

To test just jump on the interpretor and look at the version.

It used to say:

```
shell~# python
Python 2.5.2 (r252:60911, Jan  4 2009, 17:40:26)
[GCC 4.3.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pycurl
>>> pycurl.version
'libcurl/7.18.2 GnuTLS/2.4.2 zlib/1.2.3.3 libidn/1.8'
```

It will now say (if you did everything right):

```
shell~# python
Python 2.5.2 (r252:60911, Jan  4 2009, 17:40:26)
[GCC 4.3.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pycurl
>>> pycurl.version
'libcurl/7.18.2 OpenSSL/0.9.8g zlib/1.2.3.3 libidn/1.8 libssh2/0.18'
```

The reason just editing the debian/control file works here is because 
both `libcurl4-gnutls-dev` and `libcurl4-openssl-dev` use the file 
`/usr/bin/curl-config` to build its packages. One is for gnutls 
enviroments while the other is for openssl.

Comment: This answer is correct, the solution is working, and should be the accepted answer instead.

Comment: `Edit the debian/control`. Has there been some kind of update that deleted these files? I can only find a `debian` folder that resembles the names of those files! Using `pycurl-7.19.3`

Comment: Thanks this worked! Additionally I had to install `libssl-dev` in Debian, otherwise I wouldnt find the header files for compilation. Also signing failed so I used this command to build the package: `sudo dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -b -uc -us`

Comment: As @Martin wrote. It works but would be nice if @nobody update this answer with missing `libssl-dev` and different `dpkg-buildpackage` call (I got exactly the same issues and Martin's hints helped).

Answer (score 1):

Remove the pycurl module and reinstall it using pip.

```
sudo pip install pycurl
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it, the package `libcurl3` should offer OpenSSL support.